# CSV opening fine on open office on ubuntu but breaking while opening in MS office

Tags: csv

I have generated a csv file in open office but when i open it in MS office line break occurs,
The cells of csv contains html codes, and the character size of each cell is approx 15000 characters, i have removed characters like ",',',"'",'\n' etc
I can paste the content of cell which is broken also if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined the issue, there were some cells which had character count more than 32,767 and a cell in csv can't have more than this much characters.
(I didn't notice that earlier). So the csv was breaking at that point.